# no puedo hacer que mi programa respete la restricción de clave foránea de la base SQLiteStudio

Tags: java, sql, sqlite3

El procedimiento funciona correctamente, pero no elimina la línea que tiene la llave foránea en la otra tabla (no se produce el efecto CASCADE). Sin embargo cuando ejecuto la misma consulta en SqliteStudio, sí se produce el efecto cascada.

En la base de datos tengo creada esta tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE cupon (
  propietario VARCHAR REFERENCES cliente (nroCuenta),
  idOperacion NUMERIC REFERENCES operaciones (idOperacion)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  especie STRING REFERENCES bono (isin) NOT NULL,
  fecha DATE NOT NULL,
  valor DOUBLE NOT NULL
);
```

También intenté modificar la consulta de esta manera pero misteriosamente no funcionó:

```
 String queryEl = "DELETE FROM OPERACIONES WHERE IDOPERACION =      '"+idOperacion+"'; " + "DELETE FROM CUPON WHERE IDOPERACION = '"+idOperacion+"';";
```

CÓDIGO:

```
private void eliminarAct() {
                String queryEl = "DELETE FROM OPERACIONES WHERE IDOPERACION = '"+idOperacion+"'; ";

                System.out.println(queryEl);
                try {
                    conexion = Conector.dbConector();
                    consulta = conexion.createStatement();
                    consulta.execute(queryEl);
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally { 
                    try {
                        if (consulta != null)
                            consulta.close();
                        if (conexion != null){
                            conexion.close();
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
```

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: A que otra tabla te refieres? especifica  a que te refieres con "la linea que tiene la llave foranea". En el query únicamente realiza una acción sobre la tabla OPERACIONES.

Comment: Lo que estás añadiendo como comentarios deberías eliminarlos y añadir toda esa información a tu pregunta haciendo [edit] en tu pregunta.

Comment: gracias, soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Creo que el título de la pregunta no se corresponde con su contenido, échale un vistazo a eso y a mi respuesta. Espero que sea lo que buscas.

Answer (score 1):

¿Has habilitado las claves foráneas? [Aquí está documentado](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys).

Por defecto no están activadas, debes ejecutar la siguiente consulta para ello:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON
```

Tras eso las operaciones que estás realizando deberían funcionar como esperas.

He aquí el contenido de la documentación:

> As of SQLite version 3.6.19, the default setting for foreign key
>   enforcement is OFF. However, that might change in a future release of
>   SQLite. The default setting for foreign key enforcement can be
>   specified at compile-time using the SQLITE_DEFAULT_FOREIGN_KEYS
>   preprocessor macro. To minimize future problems, applications should
>   set the foreign key enforcement flag as required by the application
>   and not depend on the default setting.

Traducción:

> A partir de la versión versión 3.6.19 de SQLite la configuración
>   predeterminada para la aplicación de restricciones de clave foráneas
>   está desactivada. Sin embargo esta situación podría cambiarse en una
>   versión de SQLite posterior. La configuración predeterminada para la
>   aplicación de restricciones de clave foráneas se puede especificar
>   en tiempo de compilación utilizando la macro de preprocesador
>   SQLITE_DEFAULT_FOREIGN_KEYS. Para minimizar problemas en un futuro
>   las aplicaciones deben establecer el indicador cuando lo requiera la
>   aplicación y así no depender de la configuración predeterminada.

Answer (score 0):

A mí me sucede lo mismo, hice todo lo que dicen ahí y nada. 
Leí la documentación oficial y según ententendí, se necesita compilar nuevamente para activar las claves foraneas. Entendí perfectamente lo que hay quehacer para compilarlo, pero la documentación y herramientas que recomiendan son sobre Linux y yo trabajo con windows. Pudiera alguien compartir un .jar de SQLite compilado para aceptar las claves foraneas y actualizaciones en cascada.
Yo tengo el .jar oficial de la página, pero este no está activado para reconocer lo anterior. 
Agradecería una ayuda.